# CUPS Delayed Shutdown

Tags: shutdown

CUPS is causing a 90 second delay when trying to shutdown Ubuntu 16.04. I have spent hours following several bug reports and forum links and cannot find any way to fix this.The problem has persisted for months.Some bug reports claim the problem is fixed, but no one has integrated the fix into 16.04 updates. Adding the "proposed" repository where one of the fixes supposedly resides also did not work. Hung shutdowns was one of the many problems that made me ditch Windows and migrate to Linux several years ago, and now Ubuntu, which always remedied issues like this, is acting more like Windows every day. It looks like we have to wait for a whole new LTS operating system for a fix. In the meantime, what will happen if I remove CUPS-browsed from the system? Will it disable my printer?

Answer (score 1):

A bug was submitted on this and fixed in the package `cups-filters - 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1` My 16.04 systems have this version of the package, and don't experience the problem.  You can check the version of the package on your system with `apt-cache policy cups-filters`

If you have this version, and are still experiencing the problem, you should submit a bug report.

Anyway, unless you need your system to search for remote printers, there is no harm in stopping and disabling the `cups-browsed` service.